# Pure asp.net Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created a new project based on the Web API template, but found that it include a lot of unnecessary files that I don't need such as the regular mvc routes, css, js, cshtml files. I wanted a pure asp.net Web API application, What can I delete from this project template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty annoying - there is no "empty" template for WebAPI by default so you have to delete the following:

- /Areas/
- /Content/
- /Images/
- /Scripts/
- /Views/
- favicon.ico

This should leave you with the default generated `Controllers` and `App_Start` folders which, along with the `Global.asax` & `Web.Config` is the only thing you really need for a plain WebAPI project.

I haven't tried this, but it claims to provide a real empty WebAPI template:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a989a149-4bc3-4292-ac8a-5101ee1722d7

Comment: Is it alright to remove bundleconfig and routeconfig as well?

Comment: Yes, you could remove those too. BundleConfig is only used for minifying JS/CSS and RouteConfig is for MVC routes, not the WebAPI ones which are stored in WebApiConfig

Comment: Thanks for that, it's so annoying that it comes cluttered regardless of your needs haha

Comment: In VS2013, you can select "Empty" template and then check "include Web API" to get a minimal Web API project.